# Building a Jar using gradle - Jar hasn't sql dependency

Tags: java, gradle, jar, dependencies, build.gradle

I am trying to build a very simple Program.
I only have one dependency, the msql-jdbc.

Every build succeds. But if i try to run the jar this exception ist thrown:

> Error: Could not find or load main class metaDataDB-0.5-msSQL.jar
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: metaDataDB-0.5-msSQL.jar

If i look into the jar, for example 7zip, I see all my compiled Classes.

The content of MANIFEST.MF is as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: metaDataDB.Main
```

Maybe this helps:
[Project Structure in Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZFvF.png)

Here is my full build:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

jar{
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'metaDataDB.Main'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

group 'com.dvb'
//version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
version '0.5-msSQL'
sourceCompatibility = 17


dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
    //implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.3.1'
    // / https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '9.5.0.jre17-preview'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Did I setup something wrong? Is this an Intellij error?
I am really confused. I think it should work...

**EDIT:**
I did the mistake that i did a wrong java command.
The way i did it before:

```
java metaDataDB-0.5-msSQL.jar -login:login.txt
```

The right way to do it:

```
java -jar metaDataDB-0.5-msSQL.jar -login:login.txt
```

But know I have another Problem. My jdbc driver isn't included in the Jarfile
[image: Jarfile Contents]

Comment: How do you build the Jar? Using Gradle task?

Comment: Yes, I use the build task and jar

Comment: @Andrey Yes. As I wrote in my answer...the Problem was basicly not knowing what a fat/uber jar is.
But thanks! I think that link will help some people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem was,
that I ecexuted the Jar file in a wrong way.

I did

`java metaDataDB-0.5-msSQL.jar -login:login.txt`

The right way to do it:

`java -jar metaDataDB-0.5-msSQL.jar -login:login.txt`

After that, I realized that I didn't include the dependency needed into my Jar.
I've learned what a Fat Jar File is.

So I needed to add this to my gradle jar task:

```
 from{
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it: zipTree(it)}
    }
```

For referencere my whole build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

jar{
    manifest {
        attributes ('Main-Class': 'metaDataDB.Main')
    }
    from{
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it: zipTree(it)}
    }

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

group 'com.dvb'
//version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
version '0.5-msSQL'
sourceCompatibility = 17


dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql
   // implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.3.1'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:10.1.0.jre17-preview'
    // / https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc
    //implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:9.2.1.jre15'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

That worked for the postgressql Driver.

For the Microsoft SQL Drivers a new Problem came up.

```sh
java -jar metaDataDB-0.5-msSQL.jar -login:ms.txt
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:340)
        at java.base/sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:282)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:277)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:762)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(JarFile.java:1033)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.ensureInitialization(JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.java:72)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:883)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:848)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:780)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:675)
```

here a link to the exception:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.securityexception?view=net-6.0

I tried it to run in adminstrator mode, but that failed too...

But I guess this is a new question, and hasn't to do anything with gradle.

I guess the answer to "Building a Jar using gradle - Jar hasn't sql dependency" is answered.

I will create a new Question for the microsoft sql driver and link it here.

(I hope I did everything right)

Answer (score 0):

the problem exists in msSQL.jar, there are some missing classes I guess, you can go to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc and Implement the right jar for your JRE or experiment with different versions.

Comment: I tried some other mssql-jdbc version:
for example: 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/9.2.1.jre15
and
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/9.4.1.jre16

(also some few more)

But the endresult didn't change

Comment: I also tested it with the postgres jdbc driver...also doesn't work.

I think it doesn't find the Main.class
But why?

Comment: i don't think it's the Main.class as the error message indicate it's metaDataDB-0.5-msSQL.jar if you go to the driver jar your probably will not find it.

Comment: I tried to run the jar with java metaDataDB-0.5-msSQL.jar
But I think it would be right to run the jar with java -jar metaDataDB-0.5-msSQL.jar ... 
I am confused to be honest.